# get value from attribute "pseudo-element" using Javascript

Tags: javascript, simple-html-dom

I got DOM element which has many Div tags inside, without any class or ID.
All I want is to get values from the div Attribute "data-as-pseudo-element" using Javascript (no JQuery or any other library).

The result should be:

```
Hello How Are You
ABC
XYZ
```

```html
  <div role="none" >
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="Hello How Are You" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
      
       
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="ABC" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
      
       
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="XYZ" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
  
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do using `querySelectorAll` to find the elements, and `dataset` to extract the value:

```js
for (div of document.querySelectorAll('div[data-as-pseudo-element]')) {
  console.log(div.dataset.asPseudoElement)
}
```

```html
<div role="none" >
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="Hello How Are You" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
      
       
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="ABC" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
      
       
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="XYZ" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Thomas for the solution. I don't know why, your code works well on my testing page, but return undefined on real page (Skype call web version).

I figured out another way to do it:

```js
var tranScript = "";

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-as-pseudo-element]'), i;

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
 tranScript += divs[i].attributes["data-as-pseudo-element"].textContent.toString() +"\n" ;
}
console.log(tranScript);
```

```html
  <div role="none" >
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="Hello How Are You" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
      
       
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="ABC" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
      
       
      <div
          data-as-pseudo-element="XYZ" style="position: relative;display: inline;"
      ></div>
  
  </div>
```